# "Skipping acquire... component misspelt in sources.list?" when trying to sudo apt update

Tags: apt, software-sources

```
27 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The reason for closing this question is unclear. Neither of the cited questions addresses the quoted language (e.g., "skipping acquire of configured file"; "doesn't have the component"). There may be a solution in one or more of the answers to those questions -- but which ones, and why?